# How to return the native object value when not accessed as a list

Tags: python

I have created a class to wrap a value so that I can access it as either a list or as a normal value.  However, I can only represent the value as a string or int as opposed to its native type.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
class Options(object):
    default_option = None

class Option(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        if isinstance(value, list):
            self.value = [] + value
        else:
            self.value = [ value ]

    def __str__(self): return self.value[-1]
    def __long__(self): return self.value[-1]
    def __int__(self): return self.value[-1]
    def __float__(self): return self.value[-1]        
    def __getitem__(self, index): return self.value[index]

setattr(Options, 'opt', Option('opt', None))
print Options.opt
```

Produces the output:

```
'None'
```

But I can't perform this type of comparison:

```
if Options.opt is None:
```

Although this does work:

```
if Options.opt[0] is None:

if Options.opt != "some value":

if Options.opt == 1:
```

The point of doing this was so that I didn't have to go an refactor code elsewhere that might be referring to options as values and not lists.  The introduction of repeatable options has introduced lists into all options, thus requiring a wrapper to allow values to be accessed without needing to access it as a list.

Comment: You really do not want to do this; provide a 'as list' explicit API instead. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Take a look at [`webob.multidict.MultiDict()`](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html#webob.multidict.MultiDict) as an example; HTTP POST or GET parameters can form lists or single values; you can treat them either way but you use an explicit `.getone()` or `.getlist()` call to retrieve the values. **This is by design**.

Comment: Essentially you are saying that Perl's common `wantarray` functionality was ill conceived and whoever implemented such a thing didn't do so **by design**?

Comment: I don't know about `wantarray`; if it implicitly mixes individual values with sequence access then I'd be troubled about that, yes. I did not imply that any such mixing cannot ever be by design, but I do think such mixing is ill-advised, by design or otherwise.

Comment: It is a context driven semantic.  It allows the caller to define the return type as being either a list or scalar (two base types for all types in Perl).  The point here is that this is a trivial change implemented to a widely used object, backed by a unittest to ensure existing code still works.  Changing the API is fundamentally more damaging, since it would break all existing code that uses it (think public domain).  API change is always worse than changing internal behaviour, especially when it forces breakage to other software that uses it.

Comment: However, `def is_(a, b)` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.is_

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like implementing an `is_` method does not override the `is` operation.  Looks like this is a no-go for python, despite it being a really versatile and prototypical language in other areas.

Comment: Right, the `operator` module does **not** implement hooks; it implements functions that work just like the operators. I still think you are barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Woof! :-)  I'll accept there is no hope for me, so I'll go back to the drawing board with this one.  An acceptable API change would be one to `Options` instead of introducing the `Option` wrapper.  The `Options` class could implement a static method to obtain the list value of an option, providing a scalar type by default.  This would ensure existing API use is not broken and allows new `list` type operations.

Comment: ...By the way, if these are command-line options, have you considered `argparse`?

Comment: I am using docopt.  Docopt gives you an object that contains properties for each of the options specified in the document.  So `Options.opt_a` is the value set by `--opt-a`.  If `--opt-a` is defined without a parameter, it is a boolean.  If it is defined with a parameter, it is `None` when not set or a string of the value when set.  I have a module that wraps this to create a singleton global class where the options can be accessed by other modules part of the same suite but are able to work independently.  Enabling repeatable options changes the string to a list in the docopt return value.

Comment: I am simply trying to enable repeatable options without requiring a change to existing code, since  the enabling of repeatable options is controlled by the application and not the loadable modules that use the `Options` module flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that without the ability to override the `is` operator, this change would break existing API calls.  I will instead implement the following, which maintains the existing API while implementing a new API call to the `Options` class for obtaining `list` type options.

```
class ListOptions(object):
    pass

class Options(object):
    @classmethod
    def list(cls):
        return ListOptions

    @classmethod
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        if instance(value, list):
            value = [] + value
        else:
            value = [ value ]
        object.__setattr__(cls, name, value[-1])
        setattr(ListOptions, name, value)

setattr(Options, 'opt', Option('opt', None))
```

Now, this works as it always has, returning the last item from the list (or the only item if not a list type):

```
if Options.opt is None:
```

And, I can access the new `list` types through the `list` accesser method like so:

```
if Options.list().opt[0] is None:

if Options.list().opt != "some value":

if Options.list().opt == 1:
```

Or, through the ListOptions class:

```
if ListOptions.opt[0] is None:

if ListOptions.opt != "some value":

if ListOptions.opt == 1:
```

I'd say this is a compromise between API breakage and implementing an explicit method for accessing list types.